# print array with jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have this problem: I would print an array. It's element there are in a database. Using eclipse, I define this class:

```
package provaprovincie;


public class Provincie {

public String nome = "";
public String sigla = "";


public Provincie (String nome, String sigla)
{
    this.nome =nome;
    this.sigla =sigla;    
}
}
```

in this way, I catch the values from database:

```
 package provaprovincie;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DBQuery {


        public static ArrayList<Provincie> DB_Select_Provincie()
        {
            ArrayList<Provincie> arrpr = new ArrayList<Provincie>();

            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + "127.0.0.1" + "/" + "test" + "?" +
                        "user=" + "root" + "&password=" + "");

                PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM provincie");

                ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()){
                    String nome = rs.getString("nome");
                    String sigla = rs.getString("sigla");
                    Provincie p = new Provincie (nome, sigla);
                    arrpr.add(p);
                }

                con.close();                
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Errore con DB o Query errata");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return arrpr;
        }    
}
```

In the page ".jsp", I write:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page import="provaprovincie.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%


ArrayList<Provincie> prov = DBQuery.DB_Select_Provincie();
for (int i = 0; i < prov.size(); i++)
{
        out.print("ciao: " +prov.get(i).nome + "," +prov.get(i).sigla+".");
}
%>


</body>
</html>
```

In this way, eclipse doesn't print anything...please help me...

Comment: Are you not setup to Debug it?

Comment: soory ma I'm a beginner and I can't understand what debug write...

Comment: What do you mean by eclipse doesn't print anything? Do you have apache tomcat (or any other web server) configured. Are you starting that server after building your project? Are you opening this page on web browser using localhost:8080 in url bar?

Comment: I have apache tomcat and eclipse is configured optimally because I have work with others projects and they run normally. I open the page on the eclipse...

Comment: There may be problem with your database connectivity. Did you check the stack trace. if so attach it here. Providing additional info increases the chances of getting solution?

Comment: I have solved! In the folder "web-info" there aren't the libreries to connect to the database...thank's all for the help!